# Configure Waiting Time Between Crone Job Scheduling

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cronexpression, crontrigger

I want to make a crone expression so that scheduler run a job then after its execution is complete it wait for 2 minutes and then run next job and so on.
I am using quartz 2.2.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with a cron expression. You could schedule the job as a one-shot job and after you have done your processing in the Execute method you could schedule another one-shot job to start at 2 mins into the future.